# MouseUp not firing after MouseMove

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mouseevent

I am trying to do a tool for rectangle drawing and moving by ListBox in WPF. I use MouseLeftButtonDownOnRectangle to **select rectangle**, MouseMoveOnRectangle to **drag rectangle**, and MouseLeftButtonUpOnRectangle to **drop rectangle**. MouseLeftButtonDownOnRectangle and MouseMoveOnRectangle work ok, but MouseLeftButtonUpOnRectangle does not fire after MouseMoveOnRectangle. I have tried preview-event and non-preview-event, both of them do not work.

**XAML**

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="ShapesListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ShapesItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Rectangle.X}"/>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Rectangle.Y}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="LabelShapeFill" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Width="{Binding Rectangle.Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Rectangle.Height}"
                        Fill="{Binding Hexadecimal}"
                        Stroke="{Binding Hexadecimal}"
                        Opacity="0.1">
                    </Rectangle>

                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="LabelShapeBorder" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Width="{Binding Rectangle.Width}"
                        Height="{Binding Rectangle.Height}"
                        Stroke="{Binding Hexadecimal}"
                        StrokeThickness="1">
                    </Rectangle>
                        
                    <Grid Height="20" Margin="0 0 0 -20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="LabelShapeControlPanel">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Button Content="Delete" Width="45" Height="20" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <b:Interaction.Triggers>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownOnWindow}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownOnWindow}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpOnWindow}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonUpOnWindow}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseMoveOnWindow}"/>
            </b:EventTrigger>
        </b:Interaction.Triggers>

        <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <mb:MouseBehaviour MouseX="{Binding MouseX, Mode=OneWayToSource}" MouseY="{Binding MouseY, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
        </b:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding CurrentPhoto}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Unspecified"  Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Img}"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Img}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            Style="{StaticResource ShapesListBoxStyle}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShapesItemStyle}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedShapeIndex}">
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownOnRectangle}"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownOnRectangle}"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpOnRectangle}"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeftButtonUpOnRectangle}"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseMove">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseMoveOnRectangle}"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseMoveOnRectangle}"/>
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
        <Canvas
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Img}"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Img}">
            <Border 
                Canvas.Left="{Binding DrawStartX}"
                Canvas.Top="{Binding DrawStartY}"
                x:Name="dragSelectionBorder"
                Width="{Binding DrawWidth}"
                Height="{Binding DrawHeight}"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Hexadecimal}"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Background="LightBlue"
                Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

I use the following code to get mouse position. I suspect this code cause the problem. But I have no idea how to fix it.

**MouseBehaviour.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Core
{
    public class MouseBehaviour : Behavior<Grid>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "MouseY", typeof(double), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "MouseX", typeof(double), typeof(MouseBehaviour), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        public double MouseY
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MouseYProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseYProperty, value); }
        }

        public double MouseX
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MouseXProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MouseXProperty, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
        }

        private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
        {
            var pos = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
            MouseX = pos.X;
            MouseY = pos.Y;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I do a fair bit of drag drop which is effectively very similar in our (game) scenario and map editors.  IMO It's best to work with preview events in the parent panel.   I don't use any behaviours for this. I write event handlers. That's because whatever I do it always seems to be a one off for each usage somehow so it's not re-usable so behaviors just complicate things.

Comment: Do you mean I should write event handlers instead of behaviors for getting mouse position?

Comment: I'm saying that's what I have done.  Up to you and/or your company standards how you want to work.

Comment: Could you give me some references?

Comment: So you mean if `mb:MouseBehaviour` will be removed, then MouseUp works as expected? Or do you mean `MouseMove` trigger? What is in commands? Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?